# SVN checkout returns 400 error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, firewall

I'm trying to download the [**http**://code.**opencv.org**/svn/opencv/trunk/](http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/trunk/) repository of all of the OpenCV source code - as specified in an [OpenCV installation tutorial.](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windows-installation)

In the tutorial, the repository [**https**://code.**ros.org**/svn/opencv/trunk/](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/) is used, but they moved it to [**http**://code.**opencv.org**/svn/opencv/trunk](http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/trunk/)/, and now you need a password to access the code.ros.org repository.

Anyway, I'm using TortoiseSVN to download the SVN repository. (I get the same error with http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/)
I get this:

> Checkout from http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/trunk, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included
>
> Server sent unexpected return value (**400** Bad request. Method Unknown) in response to REPORT request for '/svn/opencv/!svn/vcc/default'

On the TortoiseSVN site I found something about this 400 error:

> You're behind a firewall which blocks DAV requests. Most firewalls do that. Either ask your Administrator to change the firewall, or access the repository with https:// instead of http:// like in https://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/ That way you connect to the repository with SSL encryption, which firewalls can't interfere with (if they don't block the SSL port completely).
> Also some virus scanners (i.e. Kapersky) are known to interfere and cause this error.

The **code.ros.org** repository is **https://**, so I *would* be able to access it, but I need a password, so I can't.

I made an account on ros.org, but it seems that I still need a password (which I don't know) to access the code repository. My username-password combination does not work.

I unblocked all of the TortoiseSVN programs in my firewall settings. Nothing changed.

I temporarily stopped my firewall to see if it was interfering with my request. I got the same error.

How can I do an svn checkout http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/ so that I don't get this error? Is there any way to make it https://?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I just manually migrated it to Serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yay! I tried it on a different network and it worked!

No idea why it didn't work in the beginning, though :(